# C++ how would you find a number with the most similar bits in N integers?

Tags: c++

For example say I have 3 integers 18 9 21
those 3 integers in binary : 10010, 10001, 10101
and say there's a number x I want that number to basically be the most similar bits for example the first digit of each number is 1 so x will start off as "1.....". The second digit of all three numbers is zero, so it will be "10...". The third digit is a mix: We have a 0,0 and a 1. but we have more zeros than 1's so x will be "100.." etc.

Is there any way to do this? I've been looking at bitwise operators and I'm just not sure how to do this? Because bitwise and doesn't really work on three numbers like this because if it sees even just one zero it will just return 0

Comment: Learn about "exclusive or".

Comment: 10001 is 17, 9 in binary is 01001 :-)

Comment: Oops my bad but now I have another problem so I can use XOR on the three numbers and get 01110 then I have to swap all bits but how do I do this? ~ swaps even the leading zeros and even the bit for the sign I just need to inverse the last 5 bits how would I do this?

Comment: @tommyd: `(~x) & 31`, assuming `x` is positive.

Comment: Why does that work?

Comment: Well actually I get it but doesn't that assume x's binary representation isn't more than 5 bits?

Comment: @tommyd: Try it out on pen and paper.

Comment: Still though what about the second thing I said?

Comment: You asked "I just need to inverse the last 5 bits how would I do this". Now are you changing the software specification? Does a career in project management await you? You're hired!!

Comment: I never said I want to inverse the last 5 bits specifically though, even in the title I said "how would I find a number with the most similar bits in N ints"

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add the bits if I were you: imagine the numbers: 17, 9 and 21, and let's write them in binary:

```
17 : 10001
 9 : 01001
21 : 10101
```

Put this in a "table" and sum your binary digits:

```
1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   1
1   0   1   0   1

2   1   1   0   3
```

... and then you say "When I have 0 or 1, I put '0', when 2 or 3, I put '1'", then you get:

```
1   0   0   0   1
```

=> your answer becomes "10001" which equals 17.